# I can't get past the opening splash screen when I try to start playing Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, technical-issues

I just tried to run Skyrim and once the splash screen appears, I hit "Play."  The splash screen blinks and pops up again. Nothing else happens, and the game does not open.

I'm stuck in a endless loop :)

It's not the first time I've run the game.  I have 28 hours of gameplay already.

I have tried:

- Restarting my PC
- Running Steam as Administrator (if I don't, I get an error message I can't completely remember, something along the lines of "Skyrim will... Modify your data")

Comment: No,restarting did not fix my problem.
Damn.

Comment: Tried : Steam -> Library -> right click Skyrim -> Properties -> Local Files tab -> Click "Verify Integrity of Game Cache" , still not working.

Comment: Deleting SkyrimPrefs.ini might so the trick.

Comment: @Bora Not worked.
Damn,it was probably the last patch,since i played this morning

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins, if you fixed your problem, post it as an "answer" and then accept it.  That way people can find it later if they have the same issue.

Comment: @Agent86 i couldnt post it as answer,because that was my first question,i had to wait 8 hours. But its there now,vote if you wish :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've fixed it. Steps for those who are having the same problems :

1. Close steam (right click on the system tray icon and choose exit)
2. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\` or whatever folder your steam is installed
3. Go to `Steam/steamapps/common/skyrim/Skyrim`
4. Delete (or move to desktop to avoid issues if it does not work) the `SkyrimPrefs.ini` file
5. Open Steam and go to : Library > Skyrim > Right Click > Properties > Local Files > Verify Integrity of Game cache
6. It will download a "missing" file, 22MB or something
7. Ready to play

I hope this helps other people with the same problem!

Comment: I had the same problem. "Verify integrity" in Steam fixed it, but I didn't need to delete or move my SkyrimPrefs.ini. If you've made changes to it, it's worth trying just "Verify Integrity" first.

Comment: you might want to mark this as the accepted answer, indicating that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the above plus removing any mods I could find but still no joy.  In the end I had to uninstall, delete the Skyrim folder with any mods in it and reinstall.  It's working fine now -  minus the mods of course.  It had been working fine previously with the mods, but the update must have conflicted with some files.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivating the Steam-Community feature solved the problem on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too. I just forgot to install service pack 3 for windows after reformating, so check if you have it :)

Comment: I already answered my own question. Thanks anyway for trying to help.By the way, SP3 Wasn't the reason