# Skyrim launcher brings up UAC dialog and never launches

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, technical-issues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't get past the opening splash screen when I try to start playing Skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39409/i-cant-get-past-the-opening-splash-screen-when-i-try-to-start-playing-skyrim)

When trying to play Skyrim on Windows 7, I double-click the icon, and the Steam launcher briefly appears

[image]

before the Skyrim laucher appears.

[image]

Clicking "PLAY", I get a UAC elevation prompt:

[image]

at which point the Skyrim launcher reappears.

[image]

#### Then, if I click "PLAY", the Skyrim launcher disappears and shortly thereafter shows me the Skyrim launcher.

[image]

Then, if I click "PLAY", the Skyrim launcher disappears and shortly thereafter shows me the Skyrim launcher.

[image]

<sup>Then, if I click "PLAY", the Skyrim launcher disappears and shortly thereafter shows me the Skyrim launcher.</sup>

[image]

...ad infinitum.

[image]

---

If I disable UAC, then i get the same steps as above, except no UAC elevation prompt appears.

Comment: Games that need privilege elevation = fail.

Comment: Did you reboot after changing UAC? Have you tried running steam as Administrator?

Comment: Run Steam as administrator, and if that doesn't work run the Skyrim executable directly as Administrator in C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\skyrim.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39409/skyrim-steam-issue

Comment: Ok but what happens if you click **Play**?

Comment: @aearon Oh, you mean if i click **Play**? The Skyrim launcher briefly disappears before showing the Skyrim launcher.

Comment: As entertaining as that many huge images is, I axed a couple and shrunk some more so your question isn't several screens (that said, it's still 3 on my laptop; way more than it should be), effectively burying the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've seen this same error yesterday. Run Steam (not sure if Administrator privilege is needed), right-click on the game name and go to Properties, then Local Files. There, click on Verify Integrity of Game Cache.

I did that yesterday on a friend's, and Skyrim launched without problems after that.

---

**OP Edit:** Results

[image]

[image]

Works!

Comment: I'll confirm that this process works. Although my game didn't find anything wrong, once I ran the 'Verify Integrity' it worked fine.